What is Unity's definition of time?
So I've been messing with both Avelog's Mouse Simulator and GameGuardian. Mostly out of fun, but partially out of finding weird game quarks that might be useful in a speedrun.
I'm going to be writing a special GameGuardian LUA script that shows the player's XYZ and velocities on screen, but I don't know what Unity's definition of "time"/"tick" is.
But, I don't know how much time a tick is.

Unity does not enforce one specific tick rate. It uses a mix of framerate-dependent variable timesteps and a configurable fixed timestep.
Its time variables are measured in seconds, those being...

wall clock seconds for Time.unscaledTime, Time.fixedUnscaledTime, Time.unscaledDeltaTime, Time.fixedUnscaledDeltaTime,  Time.realtimeSinceStartup, and their double versions.
"game simulation seconds" for Time.time, Time.fixedTime, Time.deltaTime, Time.fixedDeltaTime, Time.timeSinceLevelLoad, and their double versions. Game simulation time is affected by Time.timeScale, allowing for slow-mo effects or pausing.

Code in Update, LateUpdate, or coroutines resuming after a yield return null runs at a variable timestep, once per rendered frame, so the duration of one "tick" for these methods depends on the rendering framerate. Code should use Time.deltaTime to check how much game time elapsed since the last frame (or Time.smoothDeltaTime for a smoothed version that jitters less frame-to-frame) and use that to scale state changes to maintain a consistent rate of change relative to wall clock time.
Physics simulation and code in FixedUpdate, coroutines resuming after a yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate(), or collision/trigger callbacks ticks at a configurable rate in game time. The default is one physics tick = 0.02 game simulation seconds, so it runs 50 times per second. But developers can change this default - find it in Time.fixedDeltaTime.
Note that this is not run on a metronome, where Unity waits for 0.02 seconds to pass, then pauses whatever it's doing to run a physics step at exactly that moment, then waits another 0.02 seconds. Instead, at the beginning of a frame, it checks how much time has elapsed, and how many physics steps are "due", then it runs that many iterations back-to-back. So a single frame might have zero, one, or multiple physics ticks, depending on configuration and the current framerate.
Depending on configuration, user input and animation states can update on either the variable or fixed timestep.

See also: Time.fixedDeltaTime & Time.deltaTime in Unity which discusses what happens when a performance hitch makes a frame time exceed Time.maximumDeltaTime.

Terrific summary, +1.

Weird, but very useful! Thank you!

Unity has two kinds of ticks: Update-ticks and FixedUpdate ticks.
Update-ticks happen once per rendered frame. That means that their length depends on how long it took to render the last frame. The current value (in seconds) can be read from the global variable Time.deltaTime. Developers should use this tick for things that need to look smooth on the screen. And they should use the current value of Time.deltaTime as a multiplier to calculate any changes between frames. But sometimes developers make mistakes here or take shortcuts, which can lead to game mechanics behaving differently depending on framerate. This can lead to high or low framerates having side-effects that might be interesting to speedrunners.
FixedUpdate-ticks are used for anything that affects the physics engine. Developers should use the Fixedupdate events for anything that feeds into the physics engine. So any logic that interacts with the physics engine should be run on this tick. The length of these ticks is 0.02 seconds by default. However, the game developer can change the frequency in the project settings and even change it while the game is running. The current length of the fixed update ticks can be read from the global variable Time.fixedDeltaTime.
Also, there is a quirk about FixedUpdate ticks that might be interesting to you: When the CPU is too slow to update the physics with the desired frequency, then the physics engine might start to skip fixed updates. Which means that intentionally provoking this situation by giving the physics engine a lot to do could result in glitches which might have exploitation potential for a speedrunner.
More information about timing in Unity in the documentation.

Even the Allwinner A13 SOC has enough cpu cycles to burn for the physics skipping to not be feasible. Not only that, but Mouse Simulator is an incredibly simple game physics wise.

The other answers are correct about time, but you don't need to know what Unity's definition of time is to understand or display an object's velocity. Unity does not represent velocities in movement per tick, it represents them in units per second.
An object with a velocity of (1, 1, 1) will have moved one unit in all three axes after one second.
In most cases one second means one second in the real world, but Unity also has the ability to adjust the flow of time using Time.timeScale and if this is set to a value other than 1 then Unity's second will be longer (for Time.timeScale < 1.0) or shorter (for Time.timeScale > 1.0) than a real second.

Sure, but only if the game may is using the "physics" system for the movement, which is just one option.

@OwenReynolds If the developer is rolling their own and smoking crack then all bets are off.
